# Install SciPy on Anaconda with pip

Tags: python, scipy, pip, anaconda

I use Python on Anaconda's framework and, in order to upgrade SciPy I first uninstall it:

```
pip uninstall scipy
```

But when I tried to reinstall it:

```
pip install scipy
```

The system gives errors.

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Doesn't anaconda have its own installer, `conda' or something like that?

Comment: Using ```conda install scipy``` will give you an install based on pre-compiled binaries which just work (that's the whole purpose of anaconda). Using pip will install it from sources and requires all that fancy stuff (BLAS, LAPACK, C+Fortran compiler and co.). Read the docs of anaconda a bit to understand and reason about the usage and why you are probably using it.